# MeteorJS: Template Helpers

Tags: meteor, momentjs

Have some problem with "Where transform data from MongoDB"

I want to show date like  `10 JUL` (for this i must use `moment().format(MMM D)`) i use [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/)

**But** in my Mongo i have date in basic format `2015-07-....` ( `moment().format()`)

Where its output

```
  <td class="submitDate ">{{date}}</td>
```

I want to do something like this

```
Template.postJobs.helpers({
  date: function(){
    return this.format("MMM D");
  }
});
```

**QUESTION :** is **WHERE** i can transform date from `2015-07-.... ( moment().format())` to ``` 10 JUL``moment().format(MMM D) ``` and **HOW**

Anybody help ??

**SOLVED:**

```
  <td class="submitDate ">{{formatTime date}}</td>

UI.registerHelper('formatTime', function(context, options) {
  if(context)
    return moment(context).format('MMM D');
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a helper formatter method to do the formatting:

```
Template.postJobs.helpers({
  formatDate: function(date) {
    return date.format("MMM D");
  }
});
```

Your html template would pass the date variable into formatDate like this:

```
<td class="submitDate">{{formatDate this}}</td>
```

Comment: Hi, if I saw it right from your question, your data source field is called {{date}}. In that case you should call the helper by: {{formatDate date}}